# Чужими руками жар загребать. Значение слова "жар"

Tags: фразеология

Что означает слово "жар" во фразеологизме "Чужими руками жар загребать"?

Comment: Жар - здесь "горячие угли без пламени".

Comment: Спасибо, Серж !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь слово обозначает "горячие угли" (в печке). "Загребать" их хлопотно и немного рискованно. Отсюда поговорка "Легко чужими руками жар загребать" (пользоваться результатами чужого труда, иногда опасного) и возникший из неё фразеологизм.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander!